# How to set the viewing volume in OpenGL ES for an iPhone AR app?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, augmented-reality, frustum

I'd like to add an OpenGL ES view as an overlay to my camera view. [From this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594199/iphone-4-camera-specifications-field-of-view-vertical-horizontal-angle) and its anser I came to know the two field angles of the iPhone 4 rear camera.

How can I properly set the volume view and its perspective in the OpenGL ES view?
Shall I use `glFrustum` or `glOrthof`?

(I've seen that gluPerspective takes just one angle as parameter, is it supposing to have a square frustum instead of a rectangular one?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this can be accomplished by using simple trigonometry functions ^^. Just have a look at what a [frustrum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frustum) is, and which values are needed by `glFrustum` (have a look at [this page](http://www.google.it/imgres?imgurl=http://fly.cc.fer.hr/~unreal/theredbook/figures/Fig3-11.gif&imgrefurl=http://fly.cc.fer.hr/~unreal/theredbook/chapter03.html&h=273&w=603&sz=4&tbnid=oqayYv_XlwJ5EM%3a&tbnh=61&tbnw=135&prev=/images%3Fq%3Dglfrustum&zoom=1&q=glfrustum&usg=__YWP2uf4C27hrHiOVGlxD4g-fSv8=&sa=X&ei=cYafTP7KHcLMswabxLjmDg&ved=0CDIQ9QEwAw)). 
This stated, I do not believe that the values reported on the linked answer are the correct ones since they apply a distortion (kind of scaling along an axis) to the rendered images.