# Calculate bearing between two locations (lat, long)

Tags: android, iphone, geolocation, augmented-reality

I'm trying to develop my own augmented reality engine.

Searching on internet, I've found this useful [tutorial](http://www.invasivecode.com/blog/archives/1435). Reading it I see that the important thing is bearing between user location, point location and north.

The following picture is from that tutorial.

[image]

Following it, I wrote an Objective-C method to obtain beta:

```
+ (float) calculateBetaFrom:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)user to:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)destination
{
    double beta = 0;
    double a, b = 0;

    a = destination.latitude - user.latitude;
    b = destination.longitude - user.longitude;

    beta = atan2(a, b) * 180.0 / M_PI;
    if (beta < 0.0)
        beta += 360.0;
    else if (beta > 360.0)
        beta -= 360;

    return beta;
}
```

But, when I try it, it doesn't work very well.

So, I checked iPhone AR Toolkit, to see how it works (I've been working with this toolkit, but it is so big for me).

And, in [ARGeoCoordinate.m](https://github.com/nielswh/iPhone-AR-Toolkit/blob/master/ARKit/ARGeoCoordinate.m) there is another implementation of how to obtain beta:

```
- (float)angleFromCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)first toCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)second {

    float longitudinalDifference    = second.longitude - first.longitude;
    float latitudinalDifference     = second.latitude  - first.latitude;
    float possibleAzimuth           = (M_PI * .5f) - atan(latitudinalDifference / longitudinalDifference);

    if (longitudinalDifference > 0) 
        return possibleAzimuth;
    else if (longitudinalDifference < 0) 
        return possibleAzimuth + M_PI;
    else if (latitudinalDifference < 0) 
        return M_PI;

    return 0.0f;
}
```

It uses this formula:

```
float possibleAzimuth = (M_PI * .5f) - atan(latitudinalDifference / longitudinalDifference);
```

Why is (M_PI * .5f) in this formula? I don't understand it.

And continue searching, I've found another [page](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) talking about how to calculate distance and bearing of 2 locations. In this page there is another implementation:

```
/**
 * Returns the (initial) bearing from this point to the supplied point, in degrees
 *   see http://williams.best.vwh.net/avform.htm#Crs
 *
 * @param   {LatLon} point: Latitude/longitude of destination point
 * @returns {Number} Initial bearing in degrees from North
 */
LatLon.prototype.bearingTo = function(point) {
  var lat1 = this._lat.toRad(), lat2 = point._lat.toRad();
  var dLon = (point._lon-this._lon).toRad();

  var y = Math.sin(dLon) * Math.cos(lat2);
  var x = Math.cos(lat1)*Math.sin(lat2) -
          Math.sin(lat1)*Math.cos(lat2)*Math.cos(dLon);
  var brng = Math.atan2(y, x);

  return (brng.toDeg()+360) % 360;
}
```

Which one is the right one?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? I am interested in which solution you went with

Comment: Yes, I have to add my own answer shortly.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Calculate bearing**

```
//Source
JSONObject source = step.getJSONObject("start_location");
double lat1 = Double.parseDouble(source.getString("lat"));
double lng1 = Double.parseDouble(source.getString("lng"));

// destination
JSONObject destination = step.getJSONObject("end_location");
double lat2 = Double.parseDouble(destination.getString("lat"));
double lng2 = Double.parseDouble(destination.getString("lng"));

double dLon = (lng2-lng1);
double y = Math.sin(dLon) * Math.cos(lat2);
double x = Math.cos(lat1)*Math.sin(lat2) - Math.sin(lat1)*Math.cos(lat2)*Math.cos(dLon);
double brng = Math.toDegrees((Math.atan2(y, x)));
brng = (360 - ((brng + 360) % 360));
```

**Convert Degrees into Radians**

```
Radians = Degrees * PI / 180
```

**Convert Radians into Degrees**

```
Degrees = Radians * 180 / PI
```

Comment: You convert the value to degrees, but isn't Latitude and Longitude in degrees? Shouldn't you convert them to radians first?

Comment: I dont convert the latitude and Longitude in radius. I don't think that it make any difference

Comment: Do you tried online bearing match for testing? for ex. test on by this link. http://www.sunearthtools.com/tools/distance.php

Comment: Comparing to the tool above^, this does not give a correct result. Answer here gives the correct bearing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42619865/2063246.

Answer (score 18):

I know this question is old, but here is an easier solution:

**float bearing = loc1.bearingTo(loc2);**

Answer (score 8):

Try this for accurate result:

```
private static double degreeToRadians(double latLong) {
    return (Math.PI * latLong / 180.0);
}

private static double radiansToDegree(double latLong) {
    return (latLong * 180.0 / Math.PI);
}

public static double getBearing() {

//Source
JSONObject source = step.getJSONObject("start_location");
double lat1 = Double.parseDouble(source.getString("lat"));
double lng1 = Double.parseDouble(source.getString("lng"));

// destination
JSONObject destination = step.getJSONObject("end_location");
double lat2 = Double.parseDouble(destination.getString("lat"));
double lng2 = Double.parseDouble(destination.getString("lng"));

    double fLat = degreeToRadians(lat1);
    double fLong = degreeToRadians(lng1);
    double tLat = degreeToRadians(lat2);
    double tLong = degreeToRadians(lng2);

    double dLon = (tLong - fLong);

    double degree = radiansToDegree(Math.atan2(sin(dLon) * cos(tLat),
            cos(fLat) * sin(tLat) - sin(fLat) * cos(tLat) * cos(dLon)));

    if (degree >= 0) {
        return degree;
    } else {
        return 360 + degree;
    }
}
```

You can test bearing result on http://www.sunearthtools.com/tools/distance.php .

Comment: I've implemented the math portion of this (starting with double dLon =) and when I calculate reciprocal headings, the results aren't +/- 180*, but rather +/- 180* +/- 0.25*.  Am I the only one seeing this issue?  Is it just how the math is (imprecise) or did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 5):

In the formula

`float possibleAzimuth = (M_PI * .5f) - atan(latitudinalDifference / longitudinalDifference);`

the term `(M_PI * .5f)` means π/2 which is 90°. That means that it is the same formula that you stated at first, because regarding to the figure above it holds

β = arctan (a/b) = 90° - arctan(b/a).

So both formulas are similar if `a` refers to the difference in longitude and `b` in the difference in latitude. The last formula calculates again the same using the first part of my equation.

Comment: You refer to `a` as difference in lat and `b` as difference in long. See my response for how `a` should actually the difference in long and `b` the difference in lat. It might be useful to edit your answer to be consistent with the diagram so we don't confuse future readers any more than necessary?

Comment: Thank you, Dolbz, you are right, a and b should be changed. I edited my main answer in order to have a right one. :)

Answer (score 2):

`a` in the diagram is the longitude difference, `b` is the latitude difference therefore in the method you have written you've got them the wrong way round.

```
a = destination.latitude - user.latitude; // should be b
b = destination.longitude - user.longitude; // should be a
```

Try switching them and see what happens.

See Palund's response for answers to the rest of your questions.

Comment: Thanks, you are right: I've make a mistake with a and b. I've switched them, and I get beta = 9 degrees. But, if I use LatLon.prototype.bearingTo, with the same locations, I get beta = 7 degrees. I think the second one is more accurate, but I don't understand it isn't implemented in iPhone AR Toolkit. Thanks again.

Comment: This solve the issue. Just use arctan(b, a) instead of (a,b).

Answer (score 1):

> /*
>         Kirit vaghela answer has been modified..
>         Math.sin gives the radian value so to get degree value we need to pass Math.toRadians(value) inside Math.sin() or Math.cos()
>       */

```
    double lat1 = 39.099912;
    double lat2 = 38.627089;
    double lng1 = -94.581213;
    double lng2 = -90.200203;

    double dLon = (lng2-lng1);
    double x = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(dLon)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2));
    double y = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1))*Math.sin(Math.toRadians(lat2)) - Math.sin(Math.toRadians(lat1))*Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2))*Math.cos(Math.toRadians(dLon));
    double bearing = Math.toDegrees((Math.atan2(x, y)));
    System.out.println("BearingAngle : "+bearing);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can take a look at the code used in mixare augmented reality engine, it's on github and there's an iPhone version as well: github.com/mixare

Comment: Thanks. I'm seeing now that you have worked with this ar browser. Could you help me to find which class containing bearing calculations?

Comment: Hi, I'm not the developer of the iPhone version but according to the class documentation available at: http://code.google.com/p/mixare/wiki/FileResponsibility it swhould be class AugmentedViewController. Source is: https://github.com/mixare/mixare-iphone/blob/master/Classes/gui/tabbarControllers/augmentedView/AugmentedViewController.m

Answer (score 0):

inputs are in degrees.

```
#define PI 3.14159265358979323846
#define RADIO_TERRESTRE 6372797.56085
#define GRADOS_RADIANES PI / 180
#define RADIANES_GRADOS 180 / PI

double calculateBearing(double lon1, double lat1, double lon2, double lat2)
{
    double longitude1 = lon1;
    double longitude2 = lon2;
    double latitude1 = lat1 * GRADOS_RADIANES;
    double latitude2 = lat2 * GRADOS_RADIANES;
    double longDiff= (longitude2-longitude1) * GRADOS_RADIANES;
    double y= sin(longDiff) * cos(latitude2);
    double x= cos(latitude1) * sin(latitude2) - sin(latitude1) * cos(latitude2) * cos(longDiff);
    
    // std::cout <<__FILE__ << "." << __FUNCTION__ << " line:" << __LINE__ << "  "
    
    return fmod(((RADIANES_GRADOS *(atan2(y, x)))+360),360);
}
```