# rotate div line from two point lat long

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, dictionary

How to calculate direction from two cities lat long?

Code to calculate two latitude-longitude  to deg and width

```php
function getlocationcoords($lat, $lon)
{
    //image amp height and width;
    $height = 1096;
    $width = 543;
    $x = (($lon + 180) * ($width / 360));
    $y = ((($lat * -1) + 90) * ($height / 180)) - 7;
    return array("x" => round($x), "y" => round($y));
}

$latlongfrom = getlocationcoords($cityfrom->latitude, $cityfrom->longitude);
$latlongto = getlocationcoords($cityto->latitude, $cityto->longitude);
$width = hypot($latlongto['y'] - $latlongfrom['y'], $latlongto['x'] - $latlongfrom['x']);
$deg = atan2($latlongto['y'] - $latlongto['y'], $latlongfrom['x'] - $latlongfrom['x']) * 180 / M_PI;
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style=" overflow: hidden;">
    <img id="worldmap" src="<?php echo base_url('uploads/worldmap5.png'); ?>" alt="worldmap" title="World map">
    <div class="line" style="width: <?php echo $width ?>px;left: <?php echo $latlongfrom['x'] ?>px;  top: <?php echo $latlongfrom['y'] ?>px;  transform: rotate(<?php echo $deg ?>rad);border-bottom: 5px solid rgb(214, 0, 4); border-top-color: rgb(214, 0, 4); border-right-color: rgb(214, 0, 4); border-left-color: rgb(214, 0, 4); position: absolute; z-index: 1001;"></div>
    ;;
</div>
```

[image: map image here]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate bearing between two locations (lat, long)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8123049/calculate-bearing-between-two-locations-lat-long) not the correct language but it should be pretty straight forward to convert to php

Comment: from lahore Initial heading:138.9° Southeast and Final heading: 140.4 Southeast and from new delhhi bearing  Initial heading: 320.4
Final heading: 318.9 but how to place line on exit location in map

Comment: You posted the alomst exact same question yesterday. Not sure if it's the same account or not. But you have not done enough on your own. And placing arrows on static images like this is not going to work. Read up about how maps are compressed at the poles and you will understand that it will not be easy. Again I will say the same thing as I said yesterday use google maps, static images is not a suitable tool.

Comment: here is complete description https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Comment: I was thinking more like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kIID5FDi2JQ