# Calculating the bearing change from latitude/longitude

Tags: geolocation, geospatial, latitude-longitude

I have at hand, a dataset of GPS logs containing GPS speeds as well. Here's how the dataset looks like:

```
 id   |  gpstime   |    lat     |    lon     |  speed  
--------+------------+------------+------------+---------
 157934 | 1530099776 | 41.1825026 | -8.5996864 | 3.40901
 157934 | 1530099777 | 41.1825114 |  -8.599722 | 3.43062
 157934 | 1530099778 | 41.1825233 | -8.5997594 | 3.45739
 157934 | 1530099779 | 41.1825374 | -8.5997959 | 3.40025
 157934 | 1530099780 | 41.1825519 | -8.5998337 | 3.41673
(5 rows)
```

Now I want to compute the `bearing` change, for each point with respect to the true north.

But I have these questions I am yet to find answers to:

1. Based on my reading, I come across the formula (as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8123049/calculate-bearing-between-two-locations-lat-long) answer):

   `Bearing = atan(y,x)`

where `x` and `y` are the quantities

y = sin(B<sub>lon</sub>-A<sub>lon</sub>) * cosB<sub>lat</sub>

x = cosA<sub>lat</sub> * sinB<sub>lat</sub> -sinA<sub>lat</sub> * cosB<sub>lat</sub> * cos(B<sub>lon</sub>-A<sub>lon</sub>)

respectively for points `A` and `B`. Then from another source, the formula  [here](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html), the formula is written:

```
Bearing = atan2(y,x)
```

So I'm confused, which of the formula should I use?

2. `lat` and `lon` should be converted from degrees to radian before passing to quantities `x` and `y`. Being that the values of `lon` in my dataset are negatives, should I take the absolute value of each?

Comment: In the first document you linked it says: `longitudinalDifference = second.longitude - first.longitude;` - that's definitely wrong (unless your current position is at the equator).

Answer (score 0):

I think for GPS tracks this would be an overkill. In case the distance between two point are not to big (let's say a few hundreds of meters) I assume this simplified calculation is sufficient.

The latitude/longitude differences are app.

> Δlat = 111km * (lat<sub>1</sub> - lat<sub>2</sub>)
>
> Δlon = 111km * cos(lat) * (lon<sub>1</sub> - lon<sub>2</sub>)

So bearing would be

> bearing = atan(Δlon / Δlat) * 180/π
>
> bearing = atan(cos(lat) * (lon<sub>1</sub> - lon<sub>2</sub>) / (lat<sub>1</sub> - lat2)) * 180/ACOS(-1)

for lat use either lat<sub>1</sub> or lat<sub>2</sub> or the middle if you like.

> lat = (lat<sub>1</sub> + lat<sub>2</sub>)/2 * π/180 = (lat<sub>1</sub> + lat<sub>2</sub>)/2 * ACOS(-1)/180

Consider Δlat or Δlat could be 0

Comment: Thank you for this piece. However, I intend to use formulas in the question where bearing is calculated on `lat/lon` (distance not required). I intend to igore points where difference is 0. In the question, bearing of point in second row from point in first row should use the points `lat/lon` only. Can this be done within postgres, (by running some SQL)?

Comment: It does not use the distance. With `Δlon / Δlat` the 111km (distance of 1° latitude) are gone due to reduced fraction.

Comment: Ah OK, I see. Can this be done within postgres, (by running some SQL), so that I add another column `bearing`?

Comment: It is simple math, so should be no problem. I never worked with postgres, but you should find the syntax in documentation.