# augmented reality field of view(android)

Tags: android, augmented-reality

I want to make an augmented reality application from scratch. The app is a [gps-ar](/questions/tagged/gps-ar) that it identifies POI's.  As i have noticed you have to use compass,  accelerometer and your mobile cam. I have seen a topic which mentions in iphone and the problem in FOV(field of view). How can i calculate when the poi is in the FOV of any android device? As i have noticed the calculations depend on the specs of the mobiles cam.

Comment: have a look at [Camera.Parameters#getHorizontalViewAngle()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getHorizontalViewAngle%28%29) and the vertical pendant. You run into problems if your device does not return a value for that.

Comment: thanks for your answer. regardless of my own device, I want to work on all android devices. The problem is how can i calculate when the point of interest is the visual field of the camera. I am gonna use the gps to detect if i am close the poi and after that i will use the compass to detect the point of interest but what kind of calculations do i need to do to be sure that the poi is actually in the camera's field of view/

Comment: You can't. If the device does not provide any info about the camera fov all you can do is to ask the user to calibrate it somehow. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643075/iphone-sdk-get-calculate-camera-field-of-view-fov-augmented-reality e.g. the 10 feet from wall approach