# How can i calculate the field of view of the camera of a phone?

Tags: android, camera, augmented-reality

I need to know the field of view of the camera of the phone to make an augmented reality app, for calculate where i have to write on the camera view the name of a gps located Point of interest of a city on the correct coordinates of the screen, pointing the point of interest.

for example:

distance 5 meters: 6 meters (from left to right FOV)

distance 10 meters: 12 meters (from left to right FOV)

How to calculate it?

Comment: did u achieve calculating the distance from fov?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will never match the FOV definition for every device. (Compare [this answer for iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594199/iphone-4-camera-specifications-field-of-view-vertical-horizontal-angle).)

Every device is different when using android. Take your device, do the math (or take the results from anywhere else) and decide yourself to choose a reasonable FOV angle.

Maybe you could take account of [Camera.Parameters](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html).[getSupportedPictureSizes()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedPictureSizes%28%29) for getting the camera ratio, but that should be all you can do.

Answer (score 1):

The question is pretty old but I came across similar problem and I think there is quite reasonable solution mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/camera#group___camera_1gga8480a8f9e2ee6f1ad2489ee1649f9ef9ad0531bfb7b50c1e6dd4ff85b630b790e), at least it worked for me:

```
fov = 2 * atan2(cropW * sensorW / (2 * zoomRatio * activeArrayW), focalLength)
```

It is possible to access lens info (focal length, physical size) through camera manager from java or native code. In my case I collected necessary values using `ACameraMetadata_getConstEntry` with `ACAMERA_LENS_INFO_AVAILABLE_FOCAL_LENGTHS` and `ACAMERA_SENSOR_INFO_PHYSICAL_SIZE` parameters. I hope it may help somebody.