# iPhone 4 front camera field of view (FaceTime FOV)

Tags: iphone, augmented-reality, camera-calibration

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594199/iphone-4-camera-specifications-field-of-view-vertical-horizontal-angle) and several other online resources list the FOV of the main camera. I'm wondering the same about the FaceTime camera. Is it greater? Less?