# How to determine the size of a physical object image on a phone's screen?

Tags: iphone, image-processing, camera, sensors

Can you derive the size of a physical object image displayed on a phone's screen from its size on the CCD sensor? When you know the dimensions of a physical object, its distance from the camera and the camera's focal lenght, you can determine the size of the image produced on the camera's CCD sensor.

As I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11917700/70389), **I calculate how much larger the phone's screen is in pixels than the CCD sensor in millimeters.** So if an object's dimension on the CCD is *x*, the screen is *n*-times larger than the sensor, then the object's dimension on the screen is *x* * *n* pixels.

Is my assumption right? I measured the value of *n* for the iPhone 4 but based on the size of the screen in mm (50x70). And the screen is ca. 15 times larger than the sensor (according to my [calculations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11917700/70389)). I took several pictures of a known object from a known distance and the dimensions I got from my calculations were more or less equal to the dimensions of the object's image displayed on the screen.

Still, however, I'm not sure about the correctness of this approach. I will be grateful if you say a few words about it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure all this math is going to get you much of anywhere. In the real world (unless you're mounting the camera on a tripod and putting your subject a fixed distance), objects could be any distance from the phone.

If you have a target of known composition (say, a AR target or QR Code) printed at a known size (1 inch square), you can definitely compute the size of another object in the same focal plane based on counting pixels.

Or maybe in pictures (CC licensed photo from [psd](http://www.flickr.com/photos/psd/283969989/)):

[image: Squishing the Eiffel Tower]

Comment: You know, if it comes to the simple AR application I'm currently developing, I just had to find a way to scale the virtual objects so they seem more natural on the AR view. I was looking for a way to calculate their sizes to display them properly and I found one which gives quite good results. But just out of curiousity I wanted to know if the size comparison between the camera's sensor and the phone's screen is a good idea (especially that their width-to-height ratios differ) to determine how large the object should be on the AR screen.

Answer (score 1):

A method that seems to provide adequately good estimation - which can prove extremely accurate having ensured the precision of your input values, was derived from [this article](https://www.scantips.com/lights/subjectdistance.html#math) where it explains that having known the specifications of your sensor(sensor's width-height, output resolution), and your focal length, **without taking the zoom factor into consideration**, you can calculate size of an object in meters or in pixels given one of them correspondingly. This is achieved by calculating the pixels that an object occupies on the sensor followed by a linear conversion between real and pixel size depending on what you need. Furthermore, having known the size of an object in both real world (meters) and within the frame (pixels), you can also calculate the distance from it.

The following piece of code is tested and it provides an approximation - slightly deviated from the measured values - which imo is quite satisfactory - and as the article mentions - **the precision of the input is critical**.

```py
#Requires 1)Real object size, 2)Distance from object and returns ---> Object_size in pixels
def given_real_get_pixels(Object_width_meters,Object_height_meters,distance):
    
    Object_height_on_sensor_mms=(Focal_length*Object_height_meters)/distance
    #Object_height_on_sensor_mms2
    Object_height_pixels=(Sensor_height_pixels*Object_height_on_sensor_mms)/Sensor_height_mms

    Object_width_on_sensor_mms=(Focal_length*Object_width_meters)/distance
    Object_width_pixels=(Sensor_width_pixels*Object_width_on_sensor_mms)/Sensor_width_mms
    
    print(f'Object_actual_size={Object_width_meters} x {Object_height_meters}(meters) at {distance}(meters) distance coresponds to Object_pixel_size={Object_width_pixels} x {Object_height_pixels}(pixels)')
    return Object_height_pixels,Object_width_pixels  

#Requires 1)distance from object, 2)Object height in pixels and returns ---> Object_size in meters
def given_pixels_get_real(distance,Object_height_pixels,Object_width_pixels):
    Object_height_on_sensor_mms=(Sensor_height_mms*Object_height_pixels)/Sensor_height_pixels    
    Object_height_meters=((distance*Object_height_on_sensor_mms)/Focal_length)

    Object_width_on_sensor_mms=(Sensor_width_mms*Object_width_pixels)/Sensor_width_pixels
    Object_width_meters=((distance*Object_width_on_sensor_mms)/Focal_length)

    print(f'Object_pixel_size={Object_width_pixels} x {Object_height_pixels}(pixels) at {distance}(meters) distance corresponds to Object_actual_size={Object_width_meters} x {Object_height_meters}(meters)')
    return Object_height_meters,Object_width_meters

def given_real_and_pixels_get_distance(Object_width_meters,Object_height_meters,Object_width_pixels,Object_height_pixels):

    Object_height_on_sensor_mms=(Sensor_height_mms*Object_height_pixels)/Sensor_height_pixels
    distance_height=(Focal_length*Object_height_meters)/Object_height_on_sensor_mms

    Object_width_on_sensor_mms=(Sensor_width_mms*Object_width_pixels)/Sensor_width_pixels
    distance_width=(Focal_length*Object_width_meters)/Object_width_on_sensor_mms
        
    print(f'For obtaining an Object_pixel_size={Object_width_pixels} x {Object_height_pixels}(pixels) of an object that has Object_actual_size={Object_width_meters} x {Object_height_meters}(meters), distance must be distance_width = {distance_width}(meters) and distance_height= {distance_height}(meters) and mean_distance(suggested)={(distance_width+distance_height)/2}(meters) ')
    return distance_width,distance_height

#################################################### Define Specifications ######################################################
#Sensor 
Sensor_width_mms=7.410 #mm
Sensor_height_mms=4.980 #mm
Sensor_width_pixels=3088 #pixels
Sensor_height_pixels=2076 #pixels
#Focal length
Focal_length=9.6 #mm

######################################################### Define Parameters ######################################################
distance=125 #0.8 # meters

################################################# GET OBJECT SIZE IN PIXELS ######################################################

Object_width_meters=Object_height_meters=0.001 #meters
Object_height_pixels,Object_width_pixels=given_real_get_pixels(Object_width_meters,Object_height_meters,distance)

################################################# GET OBJECT SIZE IN METERS ######################################################
Object_width_pixels=Object_height_pixels=20
Object_height_meters,Object_width_meters=given_pixels_get_real(distance,Object_height_pixels,Object_width_pixels)

########################################### GET DISTANCE TO OBJECT IN METERS ######################################################
Object_width_meters=0.0005
Object_height_meters=0.001 #meters
Object_width_pixels=10
Object_height_pixels=20
distance_width,distance_height=given_real_and_pixels_get_distance(Object_width_meters,Object_height_meters,Object_width_pixels,Object_height_pixels)
```

Just to mention - the naming of the variables may be cumbersome but not without a good reason .. To explain a bit, all methods consider both width and height but the calculations for each one of them are implemented independently ..