# FOV of One Plus 6T?

Tags: camera, photography, fieldofview, oneplus6t

I was wondering what the Field of View is for the rear Camera is for the One Plus 6T.

The information I've been able to gather so far but I'm not sure if the information is 100% right.

4.25mm focal length (25mm equivalent) fixed lens to 35/50mm in full frame

The phone has a 1/2.6” sensor size So I should be able to calculate it using a simple formula but I can't seem to figure it out

Sony IMX519
Effective resolution in MP: 16 MP

Effective resolution in pixels: 4656 x 3496 pixels

Sensor size:    6.828 mm

Sensor Diagonal size:   1/2.6 inch

Individual pixel size:  1.22 microns

Thanks to anyone who can help.

EDIT*:
To explain further I'm creating a 3d scene using the shot I took from my phone and then setting the scene up in 3DS MAX.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAEKR.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHnmA.jpg)

References:
https://www.xda-developers.com/oneplus-6t-camera-review/

[iPhone 4 Camera Specifications - Field of View / Vertical-Horizontal Angle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594199/iphone-4-camera-specifications-field-of-view-vertical-horizontal-angle)

Answer (score 0):

This is better asked on Phys.SE.

That said, simple geometry implies that formula should be 2 arctan (Sensor size / 2 / Focal length), which suggests ~77 degrees. This however seems to be on the diagonal.

At 1.22 microns, 4656 pixels mean 5.68 mm, so you have ~66 degrees on width. Similarly, one gets ~53 degrees on height.

Comment: Thanks Mostanes. The reason I want to find out the FOV is that I'm placing a camera in a 3d scene and I need the FOV to match my phone camera (OnePlus 6T). So If I'm understanding you correctly if I use the 77 degrees you mention it should work? I shot the picture while holding the phone in Landscape mode. Or will I have to match the FOV with the Width (66) and the Height (53)?

Comment: Both width and height? It's not very clear to me what exactly do you need. Also, if you need to have a precise FOV, you're better off measuring it yourself *outside the camera*. At such high FOVs, lens are not always so linear.

Comment: I noticed now that you reference a question on SO which seems to hint at AR apps. If that's your target, see if there's some API that can return that to you, or have the users calibrate the camera with a ruler, since these back-of-the-envelope computations won't help you too much (also, beside the lens, if you don't get the raw image from the camera, there might be some crop involved too, etc.).

Comment: I've updated my post there. Also the format I get from the camera is .DNG, as I set it to RAW in the settings before taking the photo. Thanks again.

Comment: Use a paper grid for calibration. Just the FOV won't be enough.